# easy: differences between dynamic strings and regular expressions?

Tags: python, dynamic

learning regular expressions on python, but already saw about dynamic strings with Android SDK, wondering IF Dynamic Strings are a subset of regular expressions and/or the differences

cheers

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, by "dynamic strings" you mean format strings (in `'such {}'.format('constructions')`). Their purpose is contrary to that of regular expressions: using format strings you convert structured data to strings, using regular expressions you convert strings to structured data. The former task is usually a lot more deterministic and simple, but it's not exactly a subset of the task solved by regular expression (they are as different as text-to-speech and speech-to-text systems), so the syntax for the two tasks is just different.